# Are scheduled flows removed from schedule if the underlying record condition changes?

Tags: visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow, scheduled-flow

If you have a record-triggered flow that runs on a date/time field on a record, and the logic is something like "if the status picklist changes to X, run this path 5 days later", will the flow be removed from schedule if the picklist changes to a different value before the five days pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, scheduled actions won't run if the entry conditions are no longer met. This is the same behavior as time-based workflow rules, which this is meant to replace.